# Loop through data layer and display dynamic content

Tags: javascript, performance, beginner, jquery

The purpose of the pricingTest object is to grab pricing information from the dataLayer on the page and render content blocks accordingly. My goal in posting this is to hopefully receive some feedback in regards to the design pattern used and performance of the code, or anything else you see as worth pointing out. For example:

1. Is my use of a constructor implemented in a standard and acceptable way?
2. Is there anything that can be done to optimize the performance of this code?

I've been learning JavaScript for about a year and it is my first language.

```
// source of the data and details to the best of my understanding
// this is loaded in the <head> of each different page
// each page can have a different combination of 'levelsofcare'
// the 'care_type_id' of 'AL' can have a different 'name' depending on geographic location
// 'AllCareIncluded' is set for individual 'care' levels, excluding 'IL'
// 'Medicaid' and 'SemiPrivateAvailable' are each set at a global level
// 'care_type_category' and 'sort_order' are being ignored for this task
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var digitalData = {
          page: {
              pageInfo: {}
          }
      };
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      digitalData.page.pageInfo['levelsOfCare'] = [{"care_type_id":"MC","name":"Memory Care","care_type_category":"resident","sort_order":3},{"care_type_id":"AL","name":"Personal Care Home","care_type_category":"resident","sort_order":4},{"care_type_id":"IL","name":"Independent Living","care_type_category":"resident","sort_order":5}];
      digitalData.page.pageInfo['pricingIL'] = '2600';
      digitalData.page.pageInfo['pricingAL'] = '5817';
      digitalData.page.pageInfo['pricingMC'] = '8558';
      digitalData.page.pageInfo['pricingAllCareIncludedAL'] = '0';
      digitalData.page.pageInfo['pricingAllCareIncludedMC'] = '1';
      digitalData.page.pageInfo['pricingMedicaid'] = '0';
      digitalData.page.pageInfo['pricingSemiPrivateAvailable'] = '1';
    </script>
// end source of the data

var pricingTest = {
    careLevels: digitalData.page.pageInfo.levelsOfCare,
    ilPrice: digitalData.page.pageInfo.pricingIL,
    alPrice: digitalData.page.pageInfo.pricingAL,
    mcPrice: digitalData.page.pageInfo.pricingMC,
    ilCareIncluded: '0',
    alCareIncluded: digitalData.page.pageInfo.pricingAllCareIncludedAL || '0',
    mcCareIncluded: digitalData.page.pageInfo.pricingAllCareIncludedMC || '0',
    medicaid: digitalData.page.pageInfo.pricingMedicaid,
    semiPrivate: digitalData.page.pageInfo.pricingSemiPrivateAvailable,
    iconLinkTails: { 
        MC: 'mc-path-ending', 
        AL: 'al-path-ending', 
        IL: 'il-path-ending' 
    },
    descriptions: {
        MC: [
            'MC Description A',
            'MC Description B'
        ],
        AL: [
            'AL Description A',
            'AL Description B'
        ],
        IL: [
            'IL Description A',
            'IL Description B'
        ]
    },
    svgLogo: '<svg class="pricing-info__item--leaf" height="82px" version="1.1" viewbox="0 0 50 82" width="50px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">...</svg>',
    checkLargeAlMcPriceGap: function () {
        if (pricingTest.mcPrice - pricingTest.alPrice > 1500) {
            console.log("MC Price: " + pricingTest.mcPrice + "   AL Price: " + pricingTest.alPrice + "   Difference is greater than 1500");
            return true;
        }
    },
    checkIfMedicaid: function () {
        if (pricingTest.medicaid === '1') {
            return '<p class="pricing-info__footer-medicaid"><span class="fa fa-dollar"></span>Medicaid accepted at this community</p>';
        } else {
            return '';
        }
    },
    checkIfSemiPrivate: function () {
        if (pricingTest.semiPrivate === '1') {
            return '<p class="pricing-info__footer-semiprivate"><span class="fa fa-arrow-down"></span>Semiprivate rooms available at a lower cost</p>';
        } else {
            return '';
        }
    },
    init: function () {
        // polyfill Array.prototype.map
        if(!Array.prototype.map){Array.prototype.map=function(callback){var T,A,k;if(this==null){throw new TypeError("this is null or not defined");}var O=Object(this);var len=O.length>>>0;if(typeof callback!=="function"){throw new TypeError(callback+" is not a function");}if(arguments.length>1){T=arguments[1];}A=new Array(len);k=0;while(k<len){var kValue,mappedValue;if(k in O){kValue=O[k];mappedValue=callback.call(T,kValue,k,O);A[k]=mappedValue;}k++;}return A;};}
        // end polyfill
        function getYesterdaysDate() {
            var today = new Date();
            var yesterday = new Date(today);
            yesterday.setDate(today.getDate() - 1);
            var dd = yesterday.getDate();
            var mm = yesterday.getMonth() + 1;
            var yyyy = yesterday.getFullYear();
            if (dd < 10) { dd = '0' + dd; } if (mm < 10) { mm = '0' + mm; }
            yesterday = mm + '/' + dd + '/' + yyyy;
            return '<span class="pricing-info__date">As of ' + yesterday + '</span>';
        }
        var outerAnchor = document.querySelector('.communityTwoColumn');
        var communityName = document.querySelector('h1[itemprop="name"]').textContent;
        outerAnchor.insertAdjacentHTML("afterEnd", '<div id="pricingInfo"><div class="pricing-info retain retain--padded"><div class="headline3 text-center">Pricing for ' +
            communityName +
            getYesterdaysDate() +
            '</div><div class="flex-row row" id="pricing-info-row"></div><div class="pricing-info__footer text-center"><div class="pricing-info__footer-community-specials">' +
            pricingTest.checkIfMedicaid() +
            pricingTest.checkIfSemiPrivate() + '</div><p class="pricing-info__footer--heading">For more details on pricing and availability</p><div class="pricing-info__footer--ctas"><div>Call <a class="pricing-info__footer--phone" href="tel:800-350-3800">800-350-3800</a></div><div><span>or</span></div><div><a class="pricing-info__footer--form-link hidden-md hidden-lg" onclick="app.communityCTAContactForm.openMobileScrollandShowLogin(event, this)" href="#">Complete the form above</a><a class="pricing-info__footer--form-link hidden-xs hidden-sm" onclick="functionName(event)" href="#">Complete the form above</a></div></div><p class="pricing-info__footer--disclaimer"><span class="pricing-info__footer--disclaimer-asterisk">*</span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p></div></div></div>'
        );
        function getCareName(item) {
            var careProfile = [item.care_type_id, item.name];
            if (item.care_type_id === "IL") {
                careProfile.push(
                    pricingTest.iconLinkTails.IL,
                    pricingTest.descriptions.IL[0],
                    parseInt(pricingTest.ilPrice, 10).toLocaleString("en"),
                    pricingTest.ilCareIncluded,
                    pricingTest.descriptions.IL[1]
                );
            } else if (item.care_type_id === "AL") {
                careProfile.push(
                    pricingTest.iconLinkTails.AL,
                    pricingTest.descriptions.AL[0],
                    parseInt(pricingTest.alPrice, 10).toLocaleString("en"),
                    pricingTest.alCareIncluded,
                    pricingTest.descriptions.AL[1]
                );
            } else if (item.care_type_id === "MC") {
                careProfile.push(
                    pricingTest.iconLinkTails.MC,
                    pricingTest.descriptions.MC[0],
                    parseInt(pricingTest.mcPrice, 10).toLocaleString("en"),
                    pricingTest.mcCareIncluded,
                    pricingTest.descriptions.MC[1]
                );
            }
            return careProfile;
        }
        var careProfiles = pricingTest.careLevels.map(getCareName);
        var innerAnchor = document.getElementById('pricing-info-row');
        // Constructor
        function Block(careId, careName, iconLinkTail, descriptionA, price, careIncluded, descriptionB) {
            this.careId = careId;
            this.careName = careName;
            this.iconLinkTail = iconLinkTail;
            this.descriptionA = descriptionA;
            this.price = price;
            this.careIncluded = careIncluded;
            this.descriptionB = descriptionB;
            this.renderPrice = function () {
                if (this.price === "NaN" || (this.careId === "MC" && pricingTest.checkLargeAlMcPriceGap() === true)) {
                    return 'Call for Pricing';
                } else {
                    return '<p class="pricing-info__item--price-label">– Base Rental Rate –</p><p>Starting at <span id="itemPrice">$' + this.price + '</span><span class="pricing-info__item--price-asterisk">*</span>per month</p>';
                }
            };
            this.renderCareIncludedPill = function () {
                if (this.careIncluded === '1') {
                    return '<div class="pricing-info__item--care-included"><span class="fa fa-heart"></span>Care Included*</div>';
                } else {
                    return '';
                }
            };
            innerAnchor.insertAdjacentHTML(
                "beforeEnd",
                '<div class="col-md-4 text-center pricing-info__care-included-' +
                this.careIncluded +
                '" id="pricingBlock' +
                this.careId +
                '"><div class="pricing-info__item"><img src="https://www.domain.com/content/path/path/en/icons/' +
                this.iconLinkTail +
                '-icon.svg" alt="' +
                this.careName +
                ' Icon" height="84px" width="84px" /><p class="pricing-info__item--heading">' +
                this.careName +
                '</p><p class="pricing-info__item--description">' +
                this.descriptionA +
                '</p><div class="pricing-info__item--price-footer"><div class="pricing-info__item--price">' +
                this.renderPrice() +
                '</div><div class="pricing-info__item--footer"><p>' +
                this.descriptionB +
                '</p>' +
                pricingTest.svgLogo +
                '</div></div></div>' +
                this.renderCareIncludedPill() + '</div>'
            );
        }
        // pass each careProfile array as a parameter to the constructor
        for (var i = 0; i < careProfiles.length; i++) { Block.apply({}, careProfiles[i]); }
    }
};
$(document).ready(function(){ pricingTest.init(); });
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! It would be a good idea to explain the source of the data and provide a sample of what that data looks like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Old school

> *"I've been learning JavaScript for about a year and it is my first language."*

Welcome to the world of programming where learning and the eagerness to learn is a primary skill all good programmers must have stay relevant in the ever changing IT industry.

That segues me to the issue with your code. It is near **9 years** out of date, wherever you are getting your study material from it is time to look for something current.

The current draft version is ECMAScript2019 which is what you should be learning. Your code is haphazardly pre ES5 which was released in 2011.

The first line inside the init function (the Array.map polyfill) pre-dates even ES5.

### Questions

> *"Is my use of a constructor implemented in a standard and acceptable way?"*

No the standard is [ES2018](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm)/19

> *"Is there anything that can be done to optimize the performance of this code?"*

Yes, update to [ES2018](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm)/19

For a reasonably up to date reference [MDN Javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript) is not as dry as the official [ECMA-262](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm) site.

### Good points

- Your code has a consistent style and  good layout (indentation, naming format, spaces, etc), however some line lengths are a little too long.
- Correct use of equality operators, and statement block layout.
- Good naming, room for improvement but nothing to leave me guessing.

<sup><sub>**Note** I qualified the good points so to avoid CR commenting backlash</sub></sup>

### Bad points

- Bad data structuring

eg if you have a set of named items that share the same category/association move the cat name out of the names and create an object to hold the items.

```
ilPrice: digitalData.page.pageInfo.pricingIL,
alPrice: digitalData.page.pageInfo.pricingAL,
mcPrice: digitalData.page.pageInfo.pricingMC,
```

should be

```
price: {
    il: digitalData.page.pageInfo.pricingIL,
    al: digitalData.page.pageInfo.pricingAL,
    mc: digitalData.page.pageInfo.pricingMC, 
}
```

- Repetitive

  - Repeated long accessors. If you repeatably access values via a long object paths, create a reference to the object needed, don't use the full path each time. See **Ex A**
  - Repeated code. There are is a section where you have the same 7 lines repeated 3 times with the only difference between 3 is 2 characters.

**Ex A** (As your code needs a rewrite from the ground up, the example does the above using a IIFE and [default parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters) as example only)

```
price: {
    il: digitalData.page.pageInfo.pricingIL,
    al: digitalData.page.pageInfo.pricingAL,
    mc: digitalData.page.pageInfo.pricingMC, 
},


price: ((info = digitalData.page.pageInfo) => ({
    il: info.pricingIL,
    al: info.pricingAL,
    mc: info.pricingMC, 
}))(),
```

- Magic constants. There are many repeated constants as strings, parts of strings, numbers, distributed throughout your code. Move these out of the code and define them as named constants in one place. You should not have to navigate the body of the code to change a simple number, or string.
- Don't add HTML to the page via strings, use the DOM API to create and modify elements, its significantly quicker, and lets you structure your code to better fit its role.

### Summary

All in all  not bad for one year, I have seen worse code from CS post-grads with 5 years under their belts.

Just don't fall behind. If you are worried about legacy browser support use a transpiler like [Babel.js](https://babeljs.io/), don't let a tiny, <sub><sup>tiny</sup> <sub><sup><sup>tiny</sup></sup></sub></sub>  minority hold your skill development back.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback Blindman67! I'll take these notes and improve my my code and approach.